# C# program to divide file in chunks and send it

Tags: c#, encryption

I have assignment where I have to read file in chunks, encrypt it and send it. at the end I have to decrypt it and save it to file. The end file should be the same as the Original. But when I decrypt it some bytes are corrupted or not decrypted (I don't know). I anyone find the solution I will be thankfull.

Read and send file:

```
using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath)) 
{
    int bytesRead;
    var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
    {
        if (bytesRead < chunkSize) 
        {
            var smallBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, smallBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            var encrypted2 = Encrypt(smallBuffer, simetricniKljuc, iv);
            Send(ns, encrypted2);
        }
        else 
        {
            var encrypted2 = Encrypt(buffer, simetricniKljuc, iv);
            Send(ns, encrypted2);
        }
    }
}
```

Where I receive data and store it to the file:

```
int counter = 0;

while (counter < int.Parse(fileInfoArr[2])) 
{
    data = Receive(ns);
    decrypted = Decrypt(data, simetricniKljuc, iv);
    using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Klemen\Desktop\vaja5_files\Prejeto\file.txt", FileMode.Append)) 
    {
        stream.Write(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Dolzina bufferja: " + decrypted.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Encrypt and Decrypt methods:

```
public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv) 
{
    try 
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create()) 
        {
            aes.KeySize = KeyBitSize;
            aes.BlockSize = BlockBitSize;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            Console.WriteLine("Dolzina aes.Key: " + aes.Key.Length);

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV)) 
            {
                    return PerformCryptography(data, encryptor);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Napaka pri enkripciji" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv) 
{
    try 
    {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create()) 
        {
            aes.KeySize = KeyBitSize;
            aes.BlockSize = BlockBitSize;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV)) 
            {
                return PerformCryptography(data, decryptor);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Napaka pri dekripciji" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}

private byte[] PerformCryptography(byte[] data, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform) 
{
    try 
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) 
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Napaka pri PerformCryptography" + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Original file:

```
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
```

File at the end:

```
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is testô_ĘRŘźÓ^‘"xíl=test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
This is test file.
```

Comment: What is the question, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question and delete some unnecessary code.

Comment: I'm guessing `ns` is a `NetworkStream` and you've made the classic mistake of assuming that TCP gives you *messaging* rather than an endless stream of bytes. No guarantee that each call to `Receive` will get you exactly the same buffer as one call to `Send` at the other end. Sometimes you'll get two at once (or other odd combinations) and that would cause exactly the corruption you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call methods like `Encrypt` multiple bytes. CBC mode is padded, so multiple calls are going to mess things up. Instead you should try and use the streaming methods for which the .NET cryptography API was designed, and only close the `CryptoStream` *once*, which means calling `FlushFinalBlock` only once.

What happens now is that the stream is closed and the final plaintext block is written using padding and then continued. When decrypted, the padded block is decrypted, resulting in the end of some plaintext followed by *unprintable* padding.

That in itself would not result in garbage, but for CBC mode the ciphertext is also used as vector to XOR against the plaintext. So the following block is using the wrong vector (and the IV would not match anyway), and therefore it messes up the plaintext returned. After that the ciphertext block is indeed the correct vector again and decryption continues unhampered.

Use one `CryptoStream`, once, and you should be all right.

Comment: So how exactly should I change my code to work properly? I'm sorry but I'm totally new in cryptography programs. This is the first time I'm using it.

Comment: Remove the encrypt / decrypt methods. You can use methods to setup the key / IV etc., but not to also encrypt the data in the same method, as you will need to copy the data to the stream in a piecemeal fashion. Is this enough you can work with? Setup the stream once, then copy the data to it.

Comment: But when should I do the encryption if I need to Send every piece of file encrypted?

Comment: @bozo It sounds like you need to learn about streaming - you can feed a `CryptoStream` into your `NetworkStream` and do the opposite on the other side.  Do some research, modify your code, and ask a new question with the updated code if you're still struggling.